# MPMoviePlayerController when in fullscreen image freezes after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, fullscreen, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm setting a video player with MPMoviePlayerController.

My app is portrait and I wanted the video to be landscape, so in the viewController in which I present modally I force a rotation. But when the video plays the image freezes after a few seconds and the audio keeps going.

It only happens when the controlStyle is FullScreen.

Here's how I'm rotating the view:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false;
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
}
```

and how I'm calling the Video Player

```
func configureVideoPlayerAndPlay(){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(videoName, ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.height, height: self.view.frame.size.width)
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
        player.fullscreen = false
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.None
        player.play()
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't understand which you want

Comment: I want to play it fullscreen and not freeze

Comment: player.fullscreen = true try this